# Deleting or updating an entry in an SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been working on this app for most of the day and created an SQLite database that store customer information.  I have options to update and delete items from the SQLite database and am not able to figure out why it is not working (or how it is supposed to work).  I can add to the database, but am not capable of editing or deleting information.  I also run into the issue when displaying specific information when I click on a listview item.  The app crashses when I attempt to delete :

```
        Button addBtn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteCust);
    addBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            Cursor cursor = datasource.displayCurrentCustomer();
            if( cursor != null) {
                String where = CustDBOpenHelper.CustID + "=" + dbOpenHelper.CustID;
                database.delete(CustDBOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, where, null);

                startActivity(new Intent(EditCustomers.this, CustomerView.class));
            }
        }
    });
```

this is the helper :

```
public class CustDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String LOGTAG = "test";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CARDEALER.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "CUSTOMER_TABLE";
public static final String CustID = "cust_id";
public static final String FirstName = "first_name";
public static final String LastName = "last_name";
public static final String CarMake = "car_make";
public static final String CarModel = "car_model";
public static final String CarCost = "car_cost";

private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
        " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        CustID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        FirstName + " TEXT, "+
        LastName + " TEXT, " +
        CarMake + " TEXT, " +
        CarModel + " TEXT, " +
        CarCost + " NUMERIC " + ")";

public CustDBOpenHelper(Context context ) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Table created");
    }
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int NewVersion){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

I have been at this for way too long and may be easily overlooking something but I am currently at a breaking point..  I am assuming once I figure out how to delete or update my current SQLite database things will get easier from there but I have tried everything, at least is seems I have.  I am guessing that part of the issue is what I display when I click on a list view item since it always displays the first item of my SQLite database.  This code is :

```
        List<Custs> custs = datasource.findAll();
    if (custs.size() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"No customer information to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Custs> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Custs>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , custs);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custListView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            startActivity(new Intent(CustomerView.this , EditCustomers.class));
        }
    });
```

and the Logcat which shows that it crashes right at 73 which is when I try to delete an item.

```
09-10 20:54:25.497 6153-6153/mbl402.phoenix.edu.week4appni4992 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: mbl402.phoenix.edu.week4appni4992, PID: 6153
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at mbl402.phoenix.edu.week4appni4992.EditCustomers$2.onClick(EditCustomers.java:73)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)


                                                                             --------- beginning of system
```

Comment: I added the logcat

Comment: Make sure that `database` variable isnt null.

Comment: As a side note-  never append values to a SQL string.  THere's performance negatives, but even more its a security issue-  read up on SQL injection for details.  The correct way to do it is to use "cust_id=?" and pass the value in as  a parameter.

Comment: How can I make sure the database variable is not null?  I did see that come up while trying to debug but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public boolean UpdateData(String ID, String First, String Last, String  MAKE, String MODEL, String Cost) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, First);
    cv.put(CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, Last);
    cv.put(CAR_MAKE, MAKE);
    cv.put(CAR_MODEL, MODEL);
    cv.put(COST, Cost);
    db.update(Table_name, cv, "ID = ?", new String[]{ID});
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteData(String ID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(Table_name, "ID =?", new String[]{ID});
}
```

This is what I used to complete a similar project

Comment: That looks way too similar!  But thanks!  it did the trick for the most part.  I had gotten things figured out but was stuck looking at the ID for the deleteData as an Int vs a String...  I am still not 100% as to what the ID = ? means, what does that do besides make the id equal to nothing? or is it waiting for the id?

Answer (score 0):

**For Update**
use this method to pass customerId of which Name you want to update

```
    public void updateFirstName(CustId custid, String firstname) {
       final SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       final String[] args = {custid};
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(CustDBOpenHelper.FirstName, firstname);
       db.update(CustDBOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, CustDBOpenHelper.CustID + "=?", args);
    }
```

**For DELETE**

```
   public boolean deleteCustomer(CustId custid) {
       final SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       final String[] args = {custid};
       return db.delete(CustDBOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, CustDBOpenHelper.CustID + "=?", args) > 0;
    }
```